# pivot_longer list of dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the function pivot_longer at multiple dataframes at once. I thought the way to go was to put all dataframes in a list and use lapply. However I am getting an error.

> Error: `matches()` must be used within a *selecting* function. i See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

If I use the pivot_longer on an individual dataframe, the pivot_longer gives no error and gives desired result. Does anyone know where I go wrong?

**Code**

```
files_J21<-list.files(pattern = "(2021)")
DATA_J21<-lapply(files_J21, read_excel)
DATA_J21<-lapply(DATA_J21,pivot_longer(cols=matches(".+[ ][0-9]{2}"),
               names_to=c(".value","Month"),
               names_pattern="(.+)[ ]([0-9]{2})"))
```

Thanks for the help, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: Change `pivot_longer(` to `function(x) pivot_longer(x,` or `. %>% pivot_longer(` or `\(x) pivot_longer(x,` (available for R 4.1.0 and above).

Comment: Your syntax in your second call to `lapply` is incorrect.  See the online help for how to pass additional parameters to the function being applied.  Or, wrap the `pivot_longer` in an anonymous wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! Simple answers but made me realize there is more to lapply than I thought. not sure yet when and when not to use function(x) but I'll  figure it out.

Comment: `lapply` always requires a function as an input. Those are just different syntax sugars to define the same function. @Josse_